# angular material html tag attributes not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

i have created a new angular 4 and material project using cli. The main page contains a mdToolbar and a mdSidenav. So far it looks great but adding some attributes to the html tags like color or mode for the sidenav doesn't have any effect. Webstorm recognize as well that these attributes are not known.

any idea whats missing?

Here is the module which includes the Material modules and my custom Components. In the app.component.html there is the md-toobar and the md-sidenav. The custom component app-sidebar and app-announcement1 shows only the title so far.

The result is a toolbar in color primary, a hidden sidenav and the title of the announcement component.

thanks and best regards,

Max

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Announcement1Component } from './announcement1/announcement1.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { MdToolbarModule, MdSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Announcement1Component,
    SidebarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, MdToolbarModule, MdSidenavModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```html
<md-toolbar color="warn">
  <h1>
    {{title}}!!
  </h1>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </md-sidenav>
  <!-- primary content -->
  <app-announcement1></app-announcement1>
</md-sidenav-container>
```